# Display relation's Advanced Custom Field in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, relation

I actually need on my single blog's page to retrieve the Advanced Custom Field of a relation.

Here's my query :

```
                    <?php 
                    $ingredients = get_field('ingredients');
                    

                    if ($ingredients) {
                        echo '<ul>';
                        foreach($ingredients as $ingredient) { ?>
                            <li><?php echo get_the_title($ingredient); ?>
                                
                            </li>
                        <? }
                        echo '</ul>';
                    }
                ?>
```

The ACF i need is named "quantite".
I tried many things as :

```
                    <?php 
                    $ingredients = get_field('ingredients');
                    

                    if ($ingredients) {
                        echo '<ul>';
                        foreach($ingredients as $ingredient) { ?>
                            <li><?php echo get_the_title($ingredient); 
                                  echo get_field('quantite'); / echo the_field('quantite');
                                  echo get_field($ingredient, 'quantite'); / 
                                  echo the_field($ingredient, 'quantite');?>
                                
                            </li>
                        <?php}
                        echo '</ul>';
                    }
                ?>
```

Nothing worked. I try with and without the "echo".

Have you any ideas?

EDIT: To be more specific, all is working but the ACF. For example get_the_title($ingredient) is working. I tried with the thumbnail too, and it works. But nothing to do with the ACF.
Thx